# Can I download the Windows 10 Anniversary Update through other medias than Windows Update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm using a personalized **Windows 10** ISO that I did with some features removed like **Windows Update**, for that reason I can't use **Windows Update**.

Is there an alternative way to download the **Windows 10 Anniversary Update**?

Microsoft doesn't offer a single link to download it as a redistributable package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click on "learn more and you will taken to the Microsoft support page that will allow you to download the ISO file to your PC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhEkF.png)

source: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/08/02/how-to-get-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/

[Direct download Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history)

Comment: Yes, this media creation tool will download te iso internally and will update the system.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but the ISO given by the Media Creation Tool is the last Windows 10 release ISO with the update integrated, or is the update contents itself ready to install in any other Windows 10 version?, because I'm searching for the second option.

Comment: How can the OP click on "learn more" when he has removed Windows update from his Windows 10?

Comment: @Moab The reason for accepting the answer was that If I understood good the 5.5mb file is a online installer, and I'm not sure whether the ISO you mean is a full Windows 10 ISO with the update integrated, or just an ISO containing the update, an offline installer. Maybe if you clarify that, thanks

Comment: ISO is the full installer for W10, it can still upgrade from previous versions of W10. Your question is not clear, but Moustafa answer is correct as the stub installer is redistributable as you asked for. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Why have you accepted this non-answer?

Comment: @DavidPostill the answer didn't provided the detail but the "Learn more" webpage is linked in the article that Moustafa's gave: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @Moab, As you know a update or SP is a different thing than a full OS. I asked for the update installer (that will replace/update only the affected files by the update), not for a full Windows 10 ISO or full windows 10 installation, I think the question was clear.

Comment: @DavidPostill "Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s)" Unfortunately the answer can only be links. "Microsoft doesn't offer a single link to download it as a redistributable package?"

Comment: @Moab Then that should be made clear in the answer. At the moment the answer consists of 2 links that don't answer the question. Neither of them is a link to the MS download page (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history). If the two links don't work there is no answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way also. You don't need to download an ISO for getting an update. 
Microsoft has a tool - Windows 10 Upgradetool.exe download and run the tool.

Read here: [Installing Anniversary Update](http://www.craxworld.com/install-windows-10-anniversary-update-11936/)

Follow the instructions to install the update. I have used it myself. 
[image]

Comment: The upgrade assistant does the same thing + does an in-place upgrade. It downloads the complete ISO/ESD anyway.

Comment: Where is the ISO downloaded to?